# some faces are darker with fine normals

Tags: modeling, shaders, faces

I'm having problems with this face. It is darker than all other faces with fine normals and flat shading. How should I fix this?
[image: One face is wrong, the same on the other fireplace(it's copied)]

[image]

[image: highlited areas seem to be wrong]
here the highlited areas seem to be wrong, especially the whole plate on top

Comment: I think you might have to share an indicative sample of this one on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Do try deleting the face and refilling it, though, if you haven't already. It might help expose double vertices/faces, wrongly assigned materials, etc.

Comment: here you go [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6924" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6924/)

Comment: While i could find some wrong normals, mainly all "dvere" and "gumena rucka", i could not see the darker face you mentioned. May be because there were no textures (not complaining, could be that you can't share them), or the camera was aiming at the wrong place. Would be helpfull if you could describe it a bit more which object has the problem or when you share the file, select the problem part and save then.

Comment: Here is updated file, the troublesome face that I first posted about is not wrong(I used remesh modifier and it seems to have fixed it), but there are other examples as well. It would be reassuring to know the source of the problem.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6929" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6929/) also I'm adding a picture for the updated file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a good few materials on certain objects and i first thought that might be the reason, removing them one by one brought me to the bad one.

Problem :The material, "platne white+color?", is the reason, more specifically the "Normal Map Node" which is set to "Tangent Space".

Solution: Changed to "Object Space", all was fine, see the video below.

Little extra:
Since i always check for wrong normals when there are issues, please bear with me, as i mentioned in the comments already. Your scene has 2 objects with a few of each that i would strongly advice to correct the normals from. May not have been an issue yet, but i's generally a very good idea to keep them blue(correct) to have no issues later with renders. Glass reflection and refraction as well as subdivision as well as maybe materials can all be affected.

I put a little video here to show you the bugger and the way to correct the normals, just in case you didn't know yet.
[image: wrong normalmapping]
By fixing the material, all objects that used the same material got corrected as well. 
Also the material preview can give an indication that something might be wrong.